# Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0 Tutorials / Introductions

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

Pretty much all of the tutorials/introductions to Windows Workflow Foundation seem to be targeted at versions prior to 4.0, or are [somewhat simplistic](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2009/06/22/getting-started-with-windows-workflow-foundation-4.aspx) and don't really show me anything about WHAT the real strengths of Workflows are.

Could someone point me in the direction of some slightly meatier tutorials (clearly my google-fu is failing me), as Workflow is one of the things that I've seen the templates for in VS but never had the time or inkling to have a play with until now.

**Note:** No video tutorials/introductions/guides, please. I find them impossible to learn from.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-workflow-foundation/ is the best reference for learning and its the latest edit and as of 2017

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've discovered recently myself that there's not a lot of online content available. Check out the [Workflow Foundation 4 Resources and Community](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd980560.aspx) site on MSDN for some good articles and labs. Also, download the [WF4 Samples](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en). I've learned a lot from poking through these samples and trying things out locally.

As for the WHY of Workflow, you can read David Chappell's take [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd851337.aspx). I don't agree with some of what he claims (a bit too pie in the sky for me), but it's a good primer on the goals and rationale of WF.

Hope that helps!

Comment: the site of WF4 Resources and Community is shown removed.

Answer (score 4):

I thought this intro was pretty good, using the new (to me) guidance feature in VS 2010

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/7fe6f504-a58d-456e-8f55-e64bddc81a41

Hands On Lab for WF4 done by Ron Jacobs

Answer (score 3):

Check out the Pro WF Windows Workflow in .Net 4 book by Bruce Bukovics.  Great book imho, worth the price.

Answer (score 2):

I have amassed quite a number of resources for learning WF 4:

- [MSDN: Windows Workflow Foundation Tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735927(v=VS.90).aspx) - basically dive in all the scenarios you would see for developer WF application
  There are more info (via. MSDN blogs) but for starter, but I'm only allowed to post one link as a starter :( I think these should suffice :)

Comment: This link goes straight to tutorials for WF3.5, and there's no any links to WF4

Comment: Here is the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489462.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at endpoint.tv on MSDN Channel 9.  Plenty of good videos on WF and WCF 4.

Comment: I should perhaps have been a bit clearer in my question and eliminated videos as an option. I, personally, cannot stand learning from a video, so pretty much anything on endpoint.tv is of little use to me