# Workflow 4.0 with WCF sample

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I am looking for simple example for workflow 4.0 exposed as WCF service and hosted on IIS. Links or sample would be greatful.  Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392099/windows-workflow-foundation-4-0-tutorials-introductions/3392156#3392156

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/WCFWFServiceLibrary.aspx

http://blog.agafonov.net.ua/post/2010/10/13/WCF-2b-WF.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en

Comment: Please Let me know the beginner stuff like Hello World sample.

Answer (score 2):

Try the Introduction to Worfklow Services Hands On Lab from the [Visual Studio 2010 Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=752CB725-969B-4732-A383-ED5740F02E93&displaylang=en)

Answer (score 0):

All samples from MSDN that you can test

```
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459
```